# Cannot save column names or data in QGIS Attribute Table?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

Whenever I add a new column within the attribute table and subsequently press "save changes" (also in the attribute table), the name of the column (header) will disappear and instead there are a bunch of symbols.

After restarting QGIS, all data that I previously entered in the attribute table is gone. This happens across all of my files. It wasn't always like this but has been for some months now.

I've already reinstalled QGIS a bunch of times (running 2.18.14 but had this problem with the previous LTR)

File Format: ESRI Shapefile

Has anyone had this problem and found a solution?

[image: Attribute table after pressing "save changes" with symbols as column name instead of original title]

Comment: Which data / file format are you using?

Comment: I am using ESRI Shapefile

Comment: How are you naming the field? Are you following the shapefile naming conventions?

Comment: for the screenshot I just named it "Example". Is that a violation?

Comment: Add in a spreadsheet and remember what encoding is used. 10 characters long. Check in others .dbfs for data type coding.

Comment: Can you clarify that a bit? How do I add in a spreadsheet and how do I influence the encoding?

Comment: What encoding is set for your layer within QGIS?

Comment: The encoding for the shapefile is set to UTF-32LE

Comment: Perhaphs try with a numeric field first, use caps for the name which must be 10 chars or less.

Comment: Is the encoding set to UTF-32LE really the correct encoding that was used when creating this file? Try for a moment with UTF-8 to exlude this possible issue as this is the most used encoding.